# create id column based on activity data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `EVENTS`

```
USER  EVENT_TS             EVENT_TYPE
abc   2016-01-01 08:00:00  Login
abc   2016-01-01 08:25:00  Stuff
abc   2016-01-01 10:00:00  Stuff
abc   2016-01-01 14:00:00  Login
xyz   2015-12-31 18:00:00  Login
xyz   2016-01-01 08:00:00  Logout
```

What I need to do is produce a `session` field for each period of activity for each user. In addition, if the user has been idle for a period equal to or longer than `p_timeout` (1 hour in this case) then a new session starts at the next activity. Users don't always log out cleanly, so the logout isn't walways there...

Notes:

Logout always terminates a session
There doesn't have to be a logout or a login (because software)
Login is always a new session

Output like

```
USER  EVENT_TS             EVENT_TYPE  SESSION
abc   2016-01-01 08:00:00  Login       1
abc   2016-01-01 08:25:00  Stuff       1
abc   2016-01-01 10:00:00  Stuff       2
abc   2016-01-01 14:00:00  Login       3
xyz   2015-12-31 18:00:00  Login       1
xyz   2016-01-01 08:00:00  Logout      1
```

Any thoughts on how to acheive this?

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We're not here to do that for you, or tell you how to go about doing your project.

Comment: How can your third row exist without another Login event, since the first session will have expired at 09:25? If you do have that extra Login then this looks fairly straightforward; if not then it's trickier...

Comment: So, just to be clear - for a given user, a new session starts when a new event is > 1 hour (or is it >= , please clarify!) from the last event, OR after a Logout regardless of time? Also is it GUARANTEED that after a Logout the next session begins by Login and not anything else? (Could a Login, other than the first one, occur without a Logout?)

Comment: @AlexPoole - "trickier" = "more interesting" {:-)

Comment: @AlexPoole If it times out, no event sent to server, no new login record (fun right?)

Comment: Also: what version of Oracle? With Oracle 12, a solution using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` begs to be written, especially if the rules are complicated.

Comment: @mathguy No guarantee of a login after a logout either,. Currently assuming >= p_timeout OR logout occurs. And 11g.

Comment: So you *don't* have to log in again after your session times out; only after an explicit log out? That seems odd.

Comment: OK. Does a Logout terminate a session though, regardless of time? I assume yes, but please confirm. (To be clear: I log in, I do a few things, I log out. 10 minutes have passed. Then, 45 minutes after the initial login, after I had logged out, I log in again. It's only 35 minutes from the last event - a logout; is this still a NEW session?)

Comment: @mathguy Yeh, a logout always terminates

Comment: It also seems that a Logout belongs with the most recent non-Logout event (even if it's more than one hour from the last event) as illustrated by your last row. Right?

Comment: @mathguy Aye, indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may do what you need. I changed "user" to "usr" in the input, and "session" to "sess" in the output - I don't ever use reserved Oracle words for object names.

**Note**: as Boneist pointed out below, my solution will assign a session number of `0` to the first session, if it is a `Logout` event (or a succession of `Logout`s right at the top). If this situation can occur in the data, and if the desired behavior is to start session counts at 1 even in that case, then the definition of `flag` must be tweaked - for example, by making `flag = 1` when `lag(event_ts) over (partition by usr order by event_ts) is null` as well.

Good luck!

```
with
     events ( usr, event_ts, event_type ) as (
       select 'abc', to_timestamp('2016-01-01 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Login' from dual union all
       select 'abc', to_timestamp('2016-01-01 08:25:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Stuff' from dual union all
       select 'abc', to_timestamp('2016-01-01 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Stuff' from dual union all
       select 'abc', to_timestamp('2016-01-01 14:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Login' from dual union all
       select 'xyz', to_timestamp('2015-12-31 18:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Login' from dual union all
       select 'xyz', to_timestamp('2016-01-01 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Logout' from dual
     ),
     start_of_sess ( usr, event_ts, event_type, flag ) as (
       select usr, event_ts, event_type,
              case when event_type != 'Logout' 
                    and
                        (    event_ts >= lag(event_ts) over (partition by usr 
                                                             order by event_ts) + 1/24 
                          or event_type = 'Login'
                          or lag(event_type) over (partition by usr 
                                                   order by event_ts) = 'Logout'
                        )
                   then 1 end
       from   events
     )
select usr, event_ts, event_type,
       count(flag) over (partition by usr order by event_ts) as sess
from   start_of_sess
;
```

**Output** (timestamps use my current `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` setting):

```
USR EVENT_TS                          EVENT_TYPE   SESS
--- --------------------------------- ---------- ------
abc 01-JAN-2016 08.00.00.000000000 AM Login           1
abc 01-JAN-2016 08.25.00.000000000 AM Stuff           1
abc 01-JAN-2016 10.00.00.000000000 AM Stuff           2
abc 01-JAN-2016 02.00.00.000000000 PM Login           3
xyz 31-DEC-2015 06.00.00.000000000 PM Login           1
xyz 01-JAN-2016 08.00.00.000000000 AM Logout          1

 6 rows selected
```

Comment: A small point, and I'm not sure if it matters to the OP, but if you have a usr whose first row is a logout row, the sess will be 0. You'd need to take account of that in the lag(event_type) by treating the empty previous row as a logout row in order to include that case in the sess count (assuming event_type is not null, of course!)

Comment: @Boneist - yes, I thought about that - and I made a conscious choice to assume the input data guarantee the first event can't be a `Logout`. I should have mentioned it though. And please see the last paragraph in my other answer (for Oracle 12); I made the same assumption in this answer. I believe your solution makes the alternative assumption on consecutive `Logout`s with no other events in between. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I made the opposite assumption - and have updated my answer to indicate that *{:-) Didn't even think to do that until I saw your other answer - cheers for that!

Answer (score 4):

I think this will do the trick:

```
WITH EVENTS AS (SELECT 'abc' usr, to_date('2016-01-01 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') event_ts, 'login' event_type FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'abc' usr, to_date('2016-01-01 08:25:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') event_ts, 'Stuff' event_type FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'abc' usr, to_date('2016-01-01 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') event_ts, 'Stuff' event_type FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'abc' usr, to_date('2016-01-01 14:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') event_ts, 'login' event_type FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'xyz' usr, to_date('2015-12-31 18:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') event_ts, 'login' event_type FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'xyz' usr, to_date('2016-01-01 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') event_ts, 'Logout' event_type FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'def' usr, to_date('2016-01-01 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') event_ts, 'Logout' event_type FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'def' usr, to_date('2016-01-01 08:15:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') event_ts, 'Logout' event_type FROM dual)
SELECT usr,
       event_ts,
       event_type,
       SUM(counter) OVER (PARTITION BY usr ORDER BY event_ts) session_id
FROM   (SELECT usr,
               event_ts,
               event_type,
               CASE WHEN LAG(event_type, 1, 'Logout') OVER (PARTITION BY usr ORDER BY event_ts) = 'Logout' THEN 1
                    WHEN event_type = 'Logout' THEN 0
                    WHEN event_ts - LAG(event_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY usr ORDER BY event_ts) > 1/24 THEN 1
                    WHEN event_type = 'login' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
               END counter
        FROM   EVENTS);

USR EVENT_TS            EVENT_TYPE SESSION_ID
--- ------------------- ---------- ----------
abc 2016-01-01 08:00:00 login               1
abc 2016-01-01 08:25:00 Stuff               1
abc 2016-01-01 10:00:00 Stuff               2
abc 2016-01-01 14:00:00 login               3
def 2016-01-01 08:00:00 Logout              1
def 2016-01-01 08:15:00 Logout              2
xyz 2015-12-31 18:00:00 login               1
xyz 2016-01-01 08:00:00 Logout              1
```

This solution relies on the logic-short circuiting that takes place in the CASE expression and the fact that the event_type is not null. It also assumes that multiple logouts in a row are counted as separate sessions:

1. If the previous row was a logout row (and if there is no previous row - i.e. for the first row in the set - treat it as if a logout row was present), we want to increase the counter by one. (Logouts terminate the session, so we always have a new session following a logout.)
2. If the current row is a logout, then this terminates the existing session. Therefore, the counter shouldn't be increased.
3. If the time of the current row is greater than an hour from the previous row, increase the counter by one.
4. If the current row is a login row, then it's a new session, so increase the counter by one.
5. For any other case, we don't increase the counter.

Once we've done that, it's just a matter of doing a running total on the counter.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness (for users with Oracle 12 or above), here is a solution using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```
select usr, event_ts, event_type, sess
from   events
match_recognize(
  partition by usr
  order by event_ts
  measures match_number() as sess
  all rows per match
  pattern (strt follow*)
  define follow as    event_type = 'Logout'
                   or (     event_type != 'Login'
                        and prev(event_type) != 'Logout'
                        and event_ts < prev(event_ts) + 1/24
                      )
)
;
```

Here I cover an unusual case: a `Logout` event following another `Logout` event. In such cases, I assume all consecutive `Logout`s, no matter how many and how far apart in time, belong to the same session. (If such cases are guaranteed not to occur in the data, so much the better.)

Please see also the **Note** I added to my other answer (for Oracle 11 and below) regarding the possibility of the very first event for a `usr` being a `Logout` (if that is even possible in the input data).