# SQL-query - Summarize logon time. Result as rows for each session

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having a hard time creating a nifty SQL-query for this.

[Background]

A server application is tracking when the client application connects to the server. As long as the server can communicate with the client application it continually writes "logon" rows into a table every five minutes (0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55).

[Sample data]

```
AgentID Action  Start   Stop    Duration                
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:07:11.857 2016-12-08 13:10:00.000 168,145 First "Logon" session this day.         
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:10:00.000 2016-12-08 13:15:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:15:00.000 2016-12-08 13:20:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:20:00.000 2016-12-08 13:25:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:25:00.000 2016-12-08 13:30:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:30:00.000 2016-12-08 13:35:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:35:00.000 2016-12-08 13:40:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:40:00.000 2016-12-08 13:45:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:45:00.000 2016-12-08 13:50:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:50:00.000 2016-12-08 13:55:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:55:00.000 2016-12-08 13:58:01.117 181,1148155     End session     
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:58:56.337 2016-12-08 14:00:00.000 63,662  Second "Logon" session this day.            
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:00:00.000 2016-12-08 14:05:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:05:00.000 2016-12-08 14:10:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:10:00.000 2016-12-08 14:15:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:15:00.000 2016-12-08 14:20:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:20:00.000 2016-12-08 14:25:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:25:00.000 2016-12-08 14:30:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:30:00.000 2016-12-08 14:35:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:35:00.000 2016-12-08 14:40:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:40:00.000 2016-12-08 14:45:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:45:00.000 2016-12-08 14:50:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:50:00.000 2016-12-08 14:55:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 14:55:00.000 2016-12-08 15:00:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:00:00.000 2016-12-08 15:05:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:05:00.000 2016-12-08 15:10:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:10:00.000 2016-12-08 15:15:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:15:00.000 2016-12-08 15:20:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:20:00.000 2016-12-08 15:25:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:25:00.000 2016-12-08 15:30:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:30:00.000 2016-12-08 15:35:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:35:00.000 2016-12-08 15:40:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:40:00.000 2016-12-08 15:45:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:45:00.000 2016-12-08 15:50:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:50:00.000 2016-12-08 15:55:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 15:55:00.000 2016-12-08 16:00:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:00:00.000 2016-12-08 16:05:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:05:00.000 2016-12-08 16:10:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:10:00.000 2016-12-08 16:15:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:15:00.000 2016-12-08 16:20:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:20:00.000 2016-12-08 16:25:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:25:00.000 2016-12-08 16:30:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:30:00.000 2016-12-08 16:35:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:35:00.000 2016-12-08 16:40:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:40:00.000 2016-12-08 16:45:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:45:00.000 2016-12-08 16:50:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:50:00.000 2016-12-08 16:55:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 16:55:00.000 2016-12-08 17:00:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 17:00:00.000 2016-12-08 17:05:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 17:05:00.000 2016-12-08 17:10:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 17:10:00.000 2016-12-08 17:15:00.000 300             
10  Logon   2016-12-08 17:15:00.000 2016-12-08 17:19:19.277 259,2776235     End session
```

[Expected result table from SQL-query]

```
AgentID Action  Start   Stop    Duration
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:07:11.857 2016-12-08 13:58:01.117 sum in seconds
10  Logon   2016-12-08 13:58:56.337 2016-12-08 17:19:19.277 sum in seconds
```

Comment: What query have you tried, Dernis? Also, what version of SQL Server are you using? If you are using 2012 or higher then you might take a look at `LEAD()` and/or `LAG()` functions. For a older version of SQL Server you will need a different approach.

Comment: Ok, so I had a similar challenge, I went with [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133743/create-id-column-based-on-activity-data)

Comment: MSSQL 2014 *sorry, forgot to add that*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
WITH sample_data AS (select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:07:12', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 168.145 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:20:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:20:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:25:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:25:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:45:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:45:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:50:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:50:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:55:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:55:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 13:58:01', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 181.1148155 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 13:58:56', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 63.662 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:20:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:20:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:25:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:25:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:45:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:45:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:50:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:50:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 14:55:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 14:55:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:20:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:20:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:25:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:25:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:45:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:45:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:50:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:50:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 15:55:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 15:55:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:20:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:20:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:25:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:25:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:30:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:40:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:45:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:45:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:50:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:50:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 16:55:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 16:55:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 17:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 17:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 17:05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 17:05:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 17:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 17:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 17:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 300 duration from dual union all
                     select 10 agentid, 'Logon' action, to_date('08/12/2016 17:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('08/12/2016 17:19:19', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') stop_date, 259.2776235 duration from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called "sample_data" with data in it.
-- see the following SQL for the main logic:
SELECT agentid,
       action,
       MIN(start_date) start_period,
       MAX(stop_date) end_period,
       SUM(duration) sum_in_seconds
FROM   (SELECT agentid,
               action,
               start_date,
               stop_date,
               duration,
               SUM(prep_for_grp_col) OVER (PARTITION BY agentid ORDER BY start_date, stop_date) grp
        FROM   (SELECT agentid,
                       action,
                       start_date,
                       stop_date,
                       duration,
                       CASE WHEN start_date != LAG(stop_date, 1, start_date - 1) OVER (PARTITION BY agentid ORDER BY start_date, stop_date) THEN 1
                       END prep_for_grp_col
                FROM   sample_data
                WHERE  action = 'Logon'))
GROUP BY agentid, action, grp;
```

Results:

```
   AGENTID ACTION START_PERIOD        END_PERIOD          SUM_IN_SECONDS
---------- ------ ------------------- ------------------- --------------
        10 Logon  08/12/2016 13:58:56 08/12/2016 17:19:19  12022.9396235
        10 Logon  08/12/2016 13:07:12 08/12/2016 13:58:01   3049.2598155
```

It first of all works out the start of the groups, by deciding whether the previous row's end date is the same as the current row's start date (using the `LAG()` analytic function).

Then it's a matter of doing a running total on that column (using the `SUM()` analytic function) which then labels the rows with their group - every time a new period starts, this number will increase by one.

Then it's a simple matter of doing a group over the rows to find the min/max times and the sum of the duration per each group.